# Return a vbscript regex match on multilines

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am using vbscript regex to find self-defined tags within a file.

`"\[\$[\s,\S]*\$\]"`

Unfortunately, I am doing something wrong, so it will grab all of the text between two different tags.  I know this is caused by not excluding "$]" between the pre and post tag, but I can't seem to find the right way to fix this.  For example:

```
[$String1$]
useless text
[$String2$]
```

returns

```
[$String1$]
useless text
[$String2$]
```

as one match.

I want to get

```
[$String1$]
[$String2$]
```

as two different matches.

Any help is appreciated.

Wade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RegEx is greedy and will try to match as much as it can in one go.

For this kind of matching where you have a specific format, instead of matching everything until the closing tag, try matching NOT CLOSING TAG until closing tag. This will prevent the match from jumping to the end.

```
"\[\$[^\$]*\$\]"
```

Comment: +1 That's it, worked like a charm and it works over multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `*` quantifier lazy by adding a `?`:

```
"\[\$[\s\S]*?\$\]"
```

should work.

Or restrict what you allow to be matches between your delimiters:

```
"\[\$.*\$\]"
```

will work as long as there is only one `[$String$]` section per line, and sections never span multiple lines;

```
"\[\$(?:(?!\$\])[\s\S])*\$\]"
```

checks before matching each character after a `[$` that no `$]` follows there.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use regex. try this. If your tags are always defined by `[$...$]`

```
Set objFS = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
strFile=WScript.Arguments(0)
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
strContent = objFile.ReadAll
strContent = Split(strContent,"$]")
For i=LBound(strContent) To UBound(strContent)
    m = InStr( strContent(i) , "[$" )
    If  m > 0 Then
        WScript.Echo Mid(strContent(i),m) & "$]"
    End If 
Next
```

Comment: Works, but I am going to stick with the regex solution.  Thanks.